# Getting specific HTML from a webpage with PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I am learning PHP and when I have to extract (parse) some data from a webpage that does not have an available API, I use regular expressions or a function which takes the string that is between two strings.

I would like to know if there is a more "professional", easier way to do this, since regexp are resource consuming and not the easiest thing to write right now for me.

Comment: step 1. get permission from the web site owner ...

Comment: I suggest removing the regex tag, since its not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You should never try to parse XML (*html*) using *regular-expressions*, instead get yourself a proper parser library for XML and do it the correct way. I might sound like a harder task but you'll thank yourself in the end.

Parsing could be done using one of the below, or similar resources.

- **[php.net - PHP: DOM - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)**
- **[simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net - PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)**

---

The popular and legendary answer regarding html and *regular-expressions*, poetry worth reading:

- **[stackoverflow.com - *The legendary HTML+RegExp answer!*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)**

Comment: I just received a down-vote, anyone care to explain why?

Answer (score 1):

PHP comes with a default XML parsing library for you to use in this specific case. Use `file_get_contents` in order to retrieve the HTML page and parse accordingly.

**XML**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

**file_get_contents**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php